# PHP Memory size error

Tags: php

I recently got this message after making some code changes. After I got the message, I checked the code, and I had an inefficient loop. I reverted the file back to the way it was, but I am still getting the error code. but I am still getting the same message, but I don't understand why.

My code is below.

```
function sqlquery($query = "") {
    if (empty($query)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (empty($this->CONN)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $conn = $this->CONN;
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn)or $this->error("Something wrong in query<hr>$query<hr>");
    if (!$result) {
        $this->error("something wrong in query");
        return FALSE;
    }
    if (preg_match("/^select/i", $query)) {
        $count = 0;
        $data = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data[$count] = $row;
            $count++;
        }
        mysql_free_result($result);
        return $data;
    } else {
        return mysql_insert_id();
    }
}
```

Comment: well you need to post your code and point to the line number your exhausting your memory on so we can help

Comment: I added the lines above that were giving problems. Specifically, this line:   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I recently got this message after making some code changes. After I got the message, I checked the code, and I had an inefficient loop. I reverted the file back to the way it was, but I am still getting the error code. but I am still getting the same message, why?

Because you program is still trying to use too much memory.  Possibly because you didn't really revert your code, possibly because you did revert your code but you system is running some sort of opt-code cache (apc, etc.) that needs to be cleared, or possibly because it wasn't just your code, it was also the sort of data your program interacts with.

**Temporarily** up your memory lime (it looks like you're at `64M` right now.  Up it to `128M`, then `256M`, then `512M`) until your program starts working again.  This will make it easier to debug your problem.  It may be that your program has a runaway loop and upping the memory limit won't help.

Regardless, your best friend in debugging this is [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/memory_get_usage).  This will report on how much memory PHP is using.  Either add `var_dump` debugging or logging

```
var_dump(memory_get_usage());
file_put_contents('/tmp/memory.log','Memory Use: '.memory_get_usage()."\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

until you find the loop where the memory limit keeps going up, or you find the single operation where the memory limit grows enormously.

Once you've solved the problem, don't forget to restore your memory limit.

Comment: Thanks! Memory_get_usage will be usefull for speeding up a script of mine. No memory limit error but anyway if i get where i use most of the memory....